# How to disable transaction management in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-batch

We are using spring batch to run our data processing steps. Inside every step we have the code which doesn't use transaction management. We are getting "java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed." exceptions for our db operations when run in spring batch as it starts every step in a transaction. Can somebody suggest an approach on how to disable them.

[EDIT]
I am looking for an option like the one mentioned here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/91158-legacy-integration-tasklet-transaction. This solution is not working in my case.

[EDIT]
I found a way to clear transactions in jdbc template, run my code and initialize them back. It is working for me. Is this a proper approach?

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronization;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import java.util.List;


public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = getTransactionSynchronizationsAndClear();

    try {
      /**
       * execute my code
       */
    } finally {
      initTransactionSyncs(transactionStatus);
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }

  private void initTransactionSyncs(TransactionStatus status) {
    try {
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization();
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionName(status.getName());
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.setActualTransactionActive(status.isActive());
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(status.isReadOnly());
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel(status.getIsolationLevel());
      for (TransactionSynchronization sync : GainsightCollectionUtils.nullSafeList(status.getSyncs())) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(sync);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private TransactionStatus getTransactionSynchronizationsAndClear() {
    try {
      TransactionStatus transactionStatus = new TransactionStatus();
      transactionStatus.setSyncs(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations());
      transactionStatus.setName(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName());
      transactionStatus.setReadOnly(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
      transactionStatus.setIsolationLevel(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel());
      transactionStatus.setActive(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.clear();
      return transactionStatus;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private class TransactionStatus {
    private String name;
    private boolean readOnly;
    private boolean active;
    private Integer isolationLevel;
    private List<TransactionSynchronization> syncs;

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly() {
      return readOnly;
    }

    public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
      this.readOnly = readOnly;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
      return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
      this.active = active;
    }

    public Integer getIsolationLevel() {
      return isolationLevel;
    }

    public void setIsolationLevel(Integer isolationLevel) {
      this.isolationLevel = isolationLevel;
    }

    public List<TransactionSynchronization> getSyncs() {
      return syncs;
    }

    public void setSyncs(List<TransactionSynchronization> syncs) {
      this.syncs = syncs;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your problem most likely is not caused because of how transactions are managed, but because you have a bug somewhere in your code. Trying to disable transaction management is most likely not the solution you need. However, without knowing anything about what your code does, it's not possible to help you with your *real* problem.

Comment: Hi @Jesper, my db connection pool settings has removeAbandonedTimeout=600sec which means if my code gets a connection and holds it for more than 10 mins, the pool will close it. Usually, our single db operation will not last for more than 10 mins. When transactions are enabled only one connection is used for running all my db operations in a transaction block (i.e., spring batch step) and it is going to take more than 10 mins. That's the reason I want to disable transactions in spring batch

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disable transaction, you have to enable them, because you will not be able to work with database without transactions. You can create them as in usual application (connect to db, open transaction, close transaction, close connection) but with spring you can do this with @Transactional annotation, or with xml config.